# How to modernize oracle developer produtcs gui?

Tags: oracleforms

I talking about oracle forms and oracle reports. Version less than or equal to 10g. I know those where around for a long time so I guess there may be a way to improve the GUI looks...

For oracle forms10g I saw a tool called : look and feel [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/community-paper-forms-look-and-feel-131989.pdf). But the results still looks like java GUI from the 90's...

Is there any was to modernize forms GUI (or report GUI) (at least closer to modern stuff like JQUery, Bootstarp, Telerik, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, as far as I can tell. Even the latest Forms 12c look more or less like Forms 9i. What people do is *migration* to something else - Apex, for example.